# In Excel, is it possible to create a hyperlink by combining two cells?

Tags: excel, hyperlink

```
Example:
Cell 1: http.standardlink/
Cell 2: [idnumber]
Result: http.standarlink/[idnumber]
```

Can I make the result a clickable hyperlink, so that I can quickly create a bunch of buttons to links made up of cell 1 and ID numbers?

I know you can manually make each one a clickable link, but I'm looking for a solution where I can simply put in the ID in one cell, and get a clickable link in the next.

I've previously been able to create the text version of a link by combining the values of a cell, but the actual link would have to be copied and pasted into your browser to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make. Use `HYPERLINK` formula with concatenated cells (`&`) as an argument: `=HYPERLINK($A$2&B2)`

Result:
[image]

Comment: That is beautiful, can't believe I didn't figure that myself. Can I make it only show the ID in the cell, while still linking to the generated link? (The reason I ask is because the "LINK" feature grays itself when I use this formula)

Comment: You should check HYPERLINK manual. Second argument is for name: =HYPERLINK($A$2&B2,B2)

Comment: Thank you, turns out I was making a mistake by using US formatting instead of EU for the second argument. Really appreciate the help!